# Display published time for today's posts only

Tags: date, date-time

I'm building a blog theme. I know that `the_date()` and `date()` functions display published date of posts. And I know how to get posts' published time with `the_time()` function.

I want today's posts to show published **time** and all other old posts to show published **date**. For example, today is September 8. All the posts that were published today should show published time (**08:40**, **16:30**, etc). But the posts that were published yesterday or longer before should show only date (September 07, July 26, etc).

How can I achieve this goal?

I guess there's a way to compare post's published date with today's date and make decision whether to display time or date that way. But there must be more optimal and easier way.

Comment: without comparing how will you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $post_date = get_the_date('d/m/Y');
    $today = date('d/m/Y');
    if ( $post_date == $today ) {
        echo get_the_date('h:m');
    } else {
        echo get_the_date();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
//use inside the loop
$now = time();
$post_date = get_post_time();
if ( $now - $post_date > 3600 * 24 ) {
  $date_format = get_option('date_format');
} else {      
  $date_format = get_option('time_format');
}
$date = date($date_format, $post_date);
```